# How to programatically detect if the MySql Connector/ODBC is installed? (and install it if needed)

Tags: delphi

I am thinking of the client PC here. When someone comes to run my app, they may not have the  MySql Connector/ODBC installed.

Now, I *could* just try to connect the information scheme (or mysql) database (which is preferable?) - but, if that fails, it might only mean that the database server is down. I *could* ping it, but it might be up and the MySql process not currently running.

I guess I could just install the connector anyway, even though it sounds sloppy, but not if doing so is going to noticably slow my app's start-up time.

What is the best approach?

When I do install, how do I do that from Delphi, given that the connector will be available on the d/b server, who's IP address is know?

Or ... at the moment my app is a simple .EXE, with no installer. Should I create an install which also installs the ODBC connector? (if so, can anyone recommend a good freeware install builder (with no adware or toolbar installs)?

I hope that this is clear. Please ask me if not.

Thanks.

Comment: ONe question at a time is better than multiple ones.  For an installer that's easy to learn, check out InnoSetup, and if you want to go without an installer, you could see questions already asked about embedded your runtime DLLs as resources inside your main executable, which it could then unpack and set up, if needed.

Comment: +1 thnaks. Agreed, it maybe ought to have been wo questions. But the OSBC driver isn't a DLL... I'm still not sure how to install it. Maybe I should ask how to detect it here, since I want to do it from Delphi & ank how to install on the MySql forum. Thanks for your help

Comment: Surely there is a redistributable form of the MySQL Connector/ODBC you can use, in MSI or other similar form?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To check the ODB drivers installed you must check this windows registry key

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers
```

from there you can easily write a delphi function to detect if the MySQL ODBC driver is installed

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Windows,
  Classes,
  Registry,
  SysUtils;

function ODBC_DriverInstalled(const DriverName:string) : Boolean;
Var
  Reg      : TRegistry;
  Providers: TStrings;
  i        : Integer;
begin
  Reg:=TRegistry.Create;
  Result:=False;
  try
     Reg.RootKey:=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
     if Reg.OpenKeyReadOnly('SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers') then
     begin
        Providers:=TStringList.Create;
        try
           Reg.GetValueNames(Providers);
           for i := 0 to Providers.Count-1 do
            begin
               if CompareText(DriverName,Providers[i])=0 then
               begin
                 Result:=True;
                 Break;
               end;
            end;
        finally
           Providers.Free;
        end;
     end;
  finally
     Reg.Free;
  end;
end;



begin
  try
   Writeln(ODBC_DriverInstalled('MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver'));
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

To install you have several options one can be use `inno setup` (which can read the windows registry as well to check for the odbc driver) and then install the driver included  inside of your setup file. also you can donwload the driver directly from your app using a simple HTTP GET passing one the download address located [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/)

Comment: Be aware that with 64-bit windows, this will ONLY net you the 64-bit drivers. You'll need to look in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI to find the 32-bit drivers.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to install the MySQL connector. You just need to put the right dll (depending on the server version) in the same folder as your application executable. I would recommend an installer like InnoSetup. This will also let you add start menu shortcut etc.